# jQuery click event not firing on dynamically added content

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, onclick

I have the body of a table which is appended dynamically with ajax to the table element through a partial view in ASP.NET MVC. The partial view looks something like this...

```
@model IEnumerable<Plan>
@{
    Layout = null;    
}
@foreach (var plan in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="jumpToMyPlans">@plan.Name</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

...and appended to the table element which is static in the main View...

```
<table id="myPlanTable">
</table>
```

I am trying to register an onclick event for each of these anchor elements (there are a lot currently), using the jQuery `on()` function like this...

```
jQuery('#myPlanTable').on('click', 'tbody > tr:gt(0) > td > a.jumpToMyPlans', function () {
    console.log('click');
});
```

...but the event refuses to fire. I've checked the DOM traversal in the browser console and it's definitely correct and returns the expected DOM set.

Comment: Is it a typo, or you really have different classes in markup and in selector?

Comment: I don't see dynamically added content.

Comment: jumpToMyActionPlans != jumpToMyPlans

Comment: I see missing `);` that must be a typo

Comment: Thats a typo, its jumpToMyPlans

Comment: It's a dynamically added partial view that embedded in another view at runtime. I didn't include the controller action, nor the ajax that calls it because I don't think it's relevant. But i can add it

Comment: Yes, thats a typo too, fixing these

Comment: the ajax is relevant so that we can see what is being replaced, the rest likely isn't

Comment: ajax isn't relevant, assume what is replaced is what I *said is replaced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This selection statement worked for me....

```
jQuery('#myPlanTable').on('click', 'tr:gt(0) > td > a.jumpToMyPlans', function () {
        console.log('click');
});
```

I think the problem was specifying `tbody` in the selector, which I guess is probably also dynamically generated, though not by me, I guess by the browser or something.

Answer (score 0):

When partial view is render through ajax or jquery then to bind Jquery events use "live" as following:

```
 jQuery('#myPlanTable').live('click', 'tbody > tr:gt(0) > td > a.jumpToMyPlans', function () {

        console.log('click');
    });
```

Comment: live() is deprecated in favor of on()

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
jQuery('#myPlanTable').on('click', 'tbody > tr:gt(0) > td > a.jumpToMyPlans', function () {
     console.log('click');
});
```

1) Change `a.jumpToMyActionPlans` to `a.jumpToMyPlans`

2) Add `);` to close your click handler

Comment: Sorry those were typos in my question, my fault

Answer (score -1):

I tested this and the click worked:

```
$(document).on('click', '#myPlanTable a.jumpToMyPlans' , function () {
    alert('click');
});

the html i used to test it was:

<table id="myPlanTable">
     <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="jumpToMyPlans">PAPA</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="jumpToMyPlans">Sapo</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Hm that's odd, specifying 'tbody' for me makes mine not work, but works without it

Comment: Sorry, there is no tbody in your table, it would be #myPlanTable the first selector. going to fix in the answer. Im glad it worked :)

Comment: Yeah I'm using chrome to develop and apparently it adds tbody, theader and tfooter to table elements. I was looking at the generated DOM, seeing tbody and assuming that, since i hadn't created it, it would be reference-able when actions are delegated. Clearly wrong haha, best to leave it out entirely

Comment: Incidentally, for that reason I don't think this a a duplicate of any other question, I wasn't using syntax wrong it was a browser idiosyncracy that other people might want to be aware of. Not sure why people voted this as duplicate.